# X-SendFile & mod_rewrite

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

First question on StackOverflow but this one really stumped me. So the current setup is that I have a file hosting site, of which was quite successful, until I wanted to rewrite my URLs from `https://example.net/project/filehost/?fid=XXXXXXXX` to `https://example.net/project/filehost/XXXXXXXX` and serve the file with X-SendFile assuming the file is stored in `https://example.net/project/filehost/data/XXXXXXXX`

My `.htaccess` is

```
XSendFile     On
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase     /project/filehost/
RewriteCond     %{REQUEST_FILENAME}     !-f
RewriteCond     %{REQUEST_FILENAME}     !-d
RewriteRule     ^([a-zA-Z0-9]{8})$       ?fid=$1     [L]    # Handle product requests
```

Interestingly, when I try the script, I get

```
xsendfile: cannot open file: redirect:/project/filehost/data/XXXXXXX
```

In addition, my `index.php` on `/project/filehost/index.php` is roughly

```
$tempFile = "data/" . $_GET['fid'];
header("X-Sendfile: " . $tempFile);
```

*I cannot reveal my entire code unless I have no choice*

How do I go about fixing this? If there isn't enough details, let me know.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently I had to do

```
RewriteRule     ^([a-zA-Z0-9]{8})$       ?fid=$1     [L, R=301]    # Handle product requests.
```

Credits to raminasri at [GitHub over here](https://github.com/nmaier/mod_xsendfile/issues/12#issuecomment-62214322)